# Determine if Values are within range based on pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to determine whether or a given value in a row of a `DataFrame` is within two other columns from a separate `DataFrame`, or if that estimate is zero.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 7,8], [-2, 10, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8, 9]],
                  columns=['lo1', 'up1','lo2', 'up2'])

   lo1  up1  lo2  up2
0   -1    2    1    3
1    4    6    7    8
2   -2   10   11   13
3    5    6    8    9

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [4, 6] , [5, 8], [10, 2,]],
                   columns=['pe1', 'pe2'])

   pe1  pe2
0    1    3
1    4    6
2    5    8
3   10    2
```

To be more clear, is it possible to develop a `for`-loop or use a function that can look at `pe1` and its corresponding values and determine if they are within `lo1` and `up1`, if `lo1` and `up1` cross zero, and if `pe1=0`? I am having a hard time coding this in Python.

EDIT: I'd like the output to be something like:

```
   m1  m2
0   0   3
1   4   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
```

Since the only `pe` that falls within its corresponding `lo` and `up` column are in the first row, second column, and second row, first column.

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output? Thank you :)

Comment: @richardec please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: That's better, thank you. Will you please tell me how the first item of `m1` becomes `0`?

Comment: The first item becomes zero because the distance between `lo1` and `up1` contains zero.

Comment: I'm quite confused. In your expected output, why are there only `4` and `3`? Why aren't there also `1` and `6`?

Comment: `6` doesn't fall within `lo2` and `up2` for the corresponding rows. `1` wouldn't be selected because `0` falls within `lo1` and `up1` for the corresponding rows. Sorry, there are a few conditions in this issue.

Comment: Are `df` and `df2` always going to be the same lengths?

Comment: yes, they'll always be the same length and set up in this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240687/discussion-between-aw27-and-richardec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eventually concatenate the two dataframes along the horizontal axis and then use `np.where`. This has a similar behaviour as `where` used by RJ Adriaansen.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 7,8], [-2, 10, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8, 9]],
                  columns=['lo1', 'up1','lo2', 'up2'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [4, 6] , [5, 8], [10, 2,]],
                   columns=['pe1', 'pe2'])

# concatenate dfs
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

where now `df` looks like

```sh
   lo1  up1  lo2  up2  pe1  pe2
0   -1    2    1    3    1    3
1    4    6    7    8    4    6
2   -2   10   11   13    5    8
3    5    6    8    9   10    2
```

Finally we use `np.where` and `between`

```py
for k in [1, 2]:
    df[f"m{k}"] = np.where(
        (df[f"pe{k}"].between(df[f"lo{k}"], df[f"up{k}"]) & 
         df[f"lo{k}"].gt(0)),
        df[f"pe{k}"],
        0)
```

and the result is

```sh
   lo1  up1  lo2  up2  pe1  pe2  m1  m2
0   -1    2    1    3    1    3   0   3
1    4    6    7    8    4    6   4   0
2   -2   10   11   13    5    8   0   0
3    5    6    8    9   10    2   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean mask for the required condition. For `pe1` that would be:

- value in `lo1` is smaller or equal to `pe1`
- value in `up1` is larger or equal to `pe1`
- value in `lo1` is larger than `0`

This would make this mask:

```
(df['lo1'] <= df2['pe1'])  &  (df['up1'] >= df2['pe1']) & (df['lo1'] > 0)
```

which returns:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Now you can use [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to keep the values that match `True` and replace those who don't with `0`:

```
df2['pe1'] = df2['pe1'].where((df['lo1'] <= df2['pe1']) & (df['up1'] >= df2['pe1']) & (df['lo1'] > 0), other=0)
df2['pe2'] = df2['pe2'].where((df['lo2'] <= df2['pe2']) & (df['up2'] >= df2['pe2']) & (df['lo2'] > 0), other=0)
```

Result:

|  | pe1 | pe2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |

To loop all columns:

```
for i in df2.columns:
    nr = i[2:] #remove the first two characters to get the number, then use that number to match the columns in the other df
    df2[i] = df2[i].where((df[f'lo{nr}'] <= df2[i]) & (df[f'up{nr}'] >= df2[i]) & (df[f'lo{nr}'] > 0), other=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to create a loop to do this if I have more data than just these columns?

Comment: @AW27 Sure, see updated answer

Comment: Also, I see your bullet points, I just want to make sure that `0` is not between `lo1` and `up1`

Comment: Then replace `(df[f'lo{nr}'] > 0)` with `((df[f'lo{nr}'] > 0) | (df[f'up{nr}'] < 0))`